# Solve for $n$, $5n\equiv 3 \pmod 8$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I've tried it like this
$5n≡3 \pmod 8$

$\implies 10n≡6 \pmod 8$

$\implies 2n≡6 \pmod 8$

$\implies n≡3 \pmod 4$

$\implies n=4a+3$

But when I put $a=0 \implies n=3$

putting it into the original condition we get $15≡3 \pmod 8$ which is false.

So, I'm wondering what is wrong in my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your solution is that $5n\equiv 3 \pmod 8$ is not equivalent to $10n\equiv 6 \pmod 8$.

To solve this problems you would find invertible $mod\ 8$ such that when multiplied by $5$ let rest $1$ (in this case) and multiply the equation by it. For example, $5$ is invertible $mod\ 8$ and $$5.5=25\equiv 1\pmod8,$$ so we have $$n\equiv 25n\equiv 5.5n\equiv 5.3\equiv 15\equiv 7\pmod8.$$ Therefore $n=7+8k$ is solution of the equation for all integer $k$.

Comment: Why multiplication (on both the sides) with $5$ is valid but not valid for $2$?

Also, what do you mean by to find invertible $\pmod 8$

Comment: @ankit I don't understood your first question. To find the invertible of $a$ mod $8$ means to find an integer $b $ such that $ab\equiv 1 \ (mod \ 8) $.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your solution since I don't quite understand it to begin with, but here is an alternative solution...

---

Consider the following cases:

- $n\equiv\color\red0\pmod8\implies5n\equiv5\cdot\color\red0\equiv0\pmod8$
- $n\equiv\color\red1\pmod8\implies5n\equiv5\cdot\color\red1\equiv5\pmod8$
- $n\equiv\color\red2\pmod8\implies5n\equiv5\cdot\color\red2\equiv2\pmod8$
- $n\equiv\color\red3\pmod8\implies5n\equiv5\cdot\color\red3\equiv7\pmod8$
- $n\equiv\color\red4\pmod8\implies5n\equiv5\cdot\color\red4\equiv4\pmod8$
- $n\equiv\color\red5\pmod8\implies5n\equiv5\cdot\color\red5\equiv1\pmod8$
- $n\equiv\color\red6\pmod8\implies5n\equiv5\cdot\color\red6\equiv6\pmod8$
- $n\equiv\color\red7\pmod8\implies5n\equiv5\cdot\color\red7\equiv3\pmod8$

Hence $5n\equiv3\pmod8 \iff n\equiv7\pmod8$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution is that $5n\equiv 3\pmod{8}\implies 10n\equiv 6\pmod{8}$, but $10n\equiv 6\pmod{8}\not\implies 5n\equiv 3\pmod{8}$.

For a proof that $n=4a+3$ generates all the solutions you would want to have $\iff$ after every equivalence.

Here's a correct solution.

$$5n\equiv 3\equiv -5\pmod{8}$$

$$\stackrel{:5}\iff n\equiv -1\equiv 7\pmod{8}$$

because $\gcd(5,8)=1$. All the solutions are generated by $n\equiv 7\pmod{8}$.

Comment: It's rather dangerous to divide in a ring which is not really made up of numbers – and is not a field. It's safer, from a pedagogical point of view, to multiply by the inverse of a unit.

Answer (score 0):

As $5$ and $8$ are coprime there is a single congruence class of solutions; namely $[n]=[7]$ mod $(8)$ in this case, and so $5\times7=35\equiv3\pmod{8}$. You can find the answer by trial multiplication of all numbers from $0$ to $7$ with $5$ until you hit residue $3$ in the congruence. Your answer goes wrong when you multiply by $2$ to get $10n\equiv6\pmod{8}$; this congruence equation now has two congruence classes of solutions, namely $[n]=[3]$ and $[n]=[7]$ mod $(8)$ and so you cannot find the unique congruence class solution for your original equation from here on. Sure you can simplify to $2n\equiv6\pmod{8}$, but you still have $[n]=[3]$ and $[n]=[7]$ mod $(8)$ as solutions; then dividing through by $2$ to get $n\equiv3\pmod{4}$ gives you both solutions as one congruence class $[n]=[3]$ mod $(4)$, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

$5(4a+3) \equiv 3$ (mod $8$)

You haven't solved for $a$.

$20a + 15 \equiv 3$ (mod $8$)

$4a \equiv -12 \equiv 4$ (mod $8$)

$a  \equiv 1$ (mod $8$)

$n \equiv 7$ (mod $8$)

---

The simplest trick is:

$5n \equiv 3$ (mod $8$)

$-3n \equiv 3$ (mod $8$)

$n \equiv -1$ (mod $8$)

$n \equiv 7$ (mod $8$)

Comment: Isn't it is the case that $4a ≡ 4\pmod 8$

$\implies a ≡ 1\pmod 2$     and not $\ a ≡ 1\pmod 8$

Comment: ankit : plug it in it works $1$ is the identity. $1.x \equiv x$ (mod $m$) for any $m$.

Comment: ankit :  $a \equiv 1$ (mod $2$)  does solve the equation but you want a solution (mod $8$).

Comment: ankit : note $x \equiv r \pmod {pq} \implies x \equiv r \pmod {p} \, and \, x \equiv r \pmod {q}$. $8 = 2^3$

Comment: Arthur: but if you state $a ≡ 1 \pmod 8$ then you are missing the cases namely $a ≡ 3, a ≡ 5, a ≡ 7$

Comment: Arthur: what do you want to prove from the last statement?

Comment: ankit :  $5n\equiv 3 \pmod 8$ is a linear modulo equations. $a ≡ 3, a ≡ 5, a ≡ 7$ produce the same answer for $n$.

Comment: ankit :The last statement also implies if $x  \equiv r \pmod {p} \, and \, x \equiv r \pmod {q} \implies x \equiv r \pmod {pq}$. The modulus can be split into its factors and solved individually. In the case of $2$ : $1 \equiv -1 \pmod{2}$ so $5n\equiv 3 \pmod 8$ becomes $5n\equiv 3 \pmod{2} $, $n\equiv 1  \equiv -1\pmod 2$, $n \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ fails but $n \equiv -1 \equiv 7 \pmod 8$ works.

Comment: ankit : To be clearer $a \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \to a = 1 + 2k$ , $5(4a+3) \equiv 3 \pmod 8 \to 5(4(1+2k)+3) \equiv 3 \pmod 8  \to 5.4.2k + 5(4+3) \equiv 3 \pmod 8 \to 5(4+3) \equiv 3 \pmod 8$. i.e.  $4.2k \equiv 0 \pmod 8$ it cancels out.